# express http body becoming key in key:value-pair

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm having some trouble with my Angular 2 http.post-request.

```
let body = JSON.stringify({user:'username', passw:'mypass'});
let headers = new Headers();

headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

this.http.post(`http://localhost:8090/api2/drawing/12345`, body, {headers: headers}) //TODO: remove localhost
  .subscribe((res: Response)=>{
    this.data = res.json();
    console.log(this.data);
  })
```

In my express-app, with bodyparser, the request body looks like this:

```
{ '{"user":"username","passw":"mypass"}': '' }
```

when I would expect it to look more like this:

```
{ user:"username", passw:"mypass" }
```

I have configured bodyParser like so:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not Angular2 issue.

Comment: I managed to send correct looking post request with postman. This is why I thought angular was the problem...

Comment: Actually I might be wrong. just noticed your header. Try using `application/json` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending a JSON-encoded body with a mismatched `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you want to keep the JSON body, change this:

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

to this:

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```